# Enzyme inhibitors against common cold viruses

Tags: enzymes, virology

Would some inhibitors of viral enzymes work against common cold viruses? Are there any studies? What could a treatment look like?

A lot of common cold viruses are rhino viruses which are picorna viruses. All picorna viruses contain two cysteine proteases, designated 3C and 2A according to [Handbook of Proteolytic Enzymes
Volume 2, 2013, Pages 2402-2406
David S.Wishart](https://sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780123822192005366) Would it suffice to inhibit either of them?

Comment: Common cold seems like the most damaging disease of all. With on average two weeks sickness per year and person that equals to an annual loss of GDP by 300 billion EUR in EU.

Answer (score 2):

A human enzyme involved in the production of rhinovirus capsids has been successfully inhibited.

> Fragment-derived inhibitors of human N-myristoyltransferase block capsid assembly and replication of the common cold virus https://www.nature.com/articles/s41557-018-0039-2

The article also says that targeting a human enzyme could be more efficient since the risk of mutation is lower compared to a virus enzyme.

Answer (score 0):

Pfizer has the orally administered [Paxlovid](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/medicines/human/EPAR/paxlovid) which is the protease inhibitor nirmatrelvir in combination with its preserver ritonavir.

Comment: Can you please combine both answers into one by using the edit function?

Comment: Then there would be no way to vote separately, and the two solutions are basically different.  One inhibits a virus enzyme and the other a human enzyme.

Comment: These are two possibilies for the same problem. Please put them together, otherwise I will do it.